# How to fetch response from Java web app without polling?

Tags: java, asynchronous, webhooks, polling

I have a Java web app, with an API doing a lot of reads from CouchBase. Due to this, the call simply times out quite often. I have following solutions:

1. Either make multiple calls from front-end to get data (will be using check-pointing logic, and sent data size would be based on the network bandwidth of user). What are ways to achieve this in Java Web app?
2. My web app can asynchronously update the front-end of the construction of response. Once all reads are done, the UI can read the response:

a. UI could poll (directly or indirectly via a Queuing mechanism)
b. using webhooks?

What are the ways in which 1. and 2. can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about pattern. Very typical solution is to switch to asynchronous service - this is option 2 in your question. The server receives request, validates it and replies to client with Ack(nowledgement) response that may contain Server generated ID of the request and method by which the response will be provided (typically a Queue). The client then listens on the queue to get the response correlating to the request ID.

Another option is something called Long polling. A good description of the concept could be found here: [What is HTTP Long Polling?](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)